# Is R-Package h2o affected by log4j-vulnerability? (and how to solve)

Tags: java, r, security, log4j, h2o

A vulnerability of `log4j` became public.
Amongst other packages, I am using R `shiny` and `h2o` packages.
I already found out, that `shiny` is not affected by the vulnerability, since it uses `log4js`(see https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node/issues/1105), which is an implementation in Javascript.

Now we come to `h2o`. I know that this package provides an API to the `h2o`-framework in Java. In the documentation of building `h2o` from source from github (see https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-noether/4/docs-website/developuser/quickstart_git.html), i found along the lines

```
javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -sourcepath src/main/java -classpath
"../lib/log4j/log4j-1.2.15.jar:../target/h2o.jar:../lib/hadoop/mapr2.1.3/hadoop-0.20.2-dev-core.jar"
-d classes/mapr2.1.3 src/main/java/water/hadoop/*.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
1 warning
jar cf target/h2odriver_mapr2.1.3.jar -C classes/mapr2.1.3 .
make build_inner HADOOP_VERSION=cdh3
mkdir classes/cdh3
javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -sourcepath src/main/java -classpath
"../lib/log4j/log4j-1.2.15.jar:../target/h2o.jar:../lib/hadoop/cdh3/hadoop-core-0.20.2-cdh3u6.jar" -d
classes/cdh3 src/main/java/water/hadoop/*.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
1 warning
jar cf target/h2odriver_cdh3.jar -C classes/cdh3 .
make build_inner HADOOP_VERSION=cdh4
mkdir classes/cdh4
javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -sourcepath src/main/java -classpath
"../lib/log4j/log4j-1.2.15.jar:../target/h2o.jar:../lib/hadoop/cdh4/hadoop-common.jar:../
```

It seems like `h2o` is using `log4j`, but I don't know much about Java and its dependencies.

Can anyone with more knowledge clearify whether the `h2o`-package is affected by the `log4j` vulnerability? And if so, how to solve or workaround this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: In reaction to CVE-2021-45105 H2O.ai products were upgraded to use log4j version 2.17.0. More details are in the security bulletin https://www.h2o.ai/security/bulletins/h2o-2021-001/

Answer (score 3):

A jar file is just a compressed folder with a different name. You can explore your packages looking for this information.

H2Os official statement, including affected versions and recommendations: https://www.h2o.ai/security/bulletins/h2o-2021-001/

Answer (score 3):

As stated on https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html Log4J 1.x versions are not affected by this vulnerability. And it seems that `h2o` is using `log4j-1.2.15.jar` so you are okay.